# How to force CLOSE_WAIT to stop

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I can't turn the server off and back on. I've tried killing it with a multitude of commands but I seem to end up with loads of CLOSE_WAITS still:

```
 netstat -a | grep 8043
tcp        1      0 localhost:60667         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:60830         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:60828         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:60820         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:60821         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:60818         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:60802         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:60819         localhost:8043          CLOSE_WAIT
```

I know what that the cause is due to some code crashing as I'm developing it. Whats the way to kill it? Its GNU/Linux server.

Comment: you don't kill it (you can't, it's not running). you reuse the port

Comment: When I go to restart the tomcat server its hanging as its excuting the startup.sh. I thought this was the reason is it not?

Comment: `CLOSE_WAIT` means that TCP is waiting for the local application to close the socket, a FIN having already been received by the peer. So the application must still be running. There's nothing you can do from outside except kill the process.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Though it is too late to solve your problem, I am answering this for future.

**N.B. This is for apache server. The same may apply to tomcat or others. I didn't try on others.**

I faced same problem. I closed server at a port, but got it is hanging at  `CLOSE_WAIT` state. The following command solved for me.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This is nothing but restarting apache.

Comment: yes, of course...if that doesn't work, reboot your pc...the close_wait be gone for sure, and  if it still doesn't work...buy a new one and turn it on..you shouldn't able to see those close_wait any more